# How can I update multiple rows with one column compare in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can update one column by comparing multiple columns but how can I update multiple columns with one query?
Here is my working code ;

```
Update HMI.[dbo].Mak8 SET reg2= CASE 
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.6'  THEN 200
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.8'  THEN 210
ELSE reg2 END
```

But when I tried to update multiple columns, I could not do that ;

```
Update HMI.[dbo].Mak8 SET reg2, reg3, reg4 = CASE 
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.6'  THEN 200, 250, 270
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.8'  THEN 210, 270, 300
ELSE reg2, reg3, reg4 END
```

I got this error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
How can I use it and how can use it?

Comment: *I got this error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','.* This is SQL Server (aka MS SQL), not MySQL error message. Re-tag your question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to use separate `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
UPDATE HMI.[dbo].Mak8
SET
    reg2 = CASE Mak_Ip WHEN '192.168.0.6' THEN 200
                       WHEN '192.168.0.8' THEN 210 END,
    reg3 = CASE Mak_Ip WHEN '192.168.0.6' THEN 250
                       WHEN '192.168.0.8' THEN 270 END,
    reg4 = CASE Mak_Ip WHEN '192.168.0.6' THEN 270
                       WHEN '192.168.0.8' THEN 300 END
WHERE
    Mak_Ip IN ('192.168.0.6', '192.168.0.8');
```

By the way `[dbo]` seriously looks like SQL Server syntax, but as it would have it, my answer would not really change much even if you were really using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You need to set values to each column seperately :

```
Update HMI.[dbo].Mak8 SET reg2 = (CASE 
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.6'  THEN 200
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.8'  THEN 210
END),
reg3= (CASE 
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.6'  THEN  250
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.8'  THEN  270
END),
reg4= (CASE 
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.6'  THEN  270
WHEN Mak_Ip = '192.168.0.8'  THEN  300
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice opportunity to use a `values` statement:

```
UPDATE m
    SET reg2 = v.reg2,
        reg3 = v.reg3,
        reg4 = v.reg4
    FROM HMI.[dbo].Mak8 m JOIN
         (VALUES ('192.168.0.6', 200, 250, 270),
                 ('192.168.0.6', 210, 270, 300)
         ) v(Mak_Ip, reg2, reg3, reg4)
         ON m.Mak_Ip = v.Mak_Ip;
```

This makes it particularly simple to add new ips and to add new columns, if you need.